# ¿Como se contestan preguntas que llevan un "no" al inicio?

Tags: preguntas

El español es mi idioma nativo, pero siempre he tenido esta duda, por ejemplo, si yo le pregunto a alguien:

> ¿Tienes frío?

Esta persona podría contestar

- Sí.
- No.
- Sí, si tengo frío.
- No, no tengo frío.

Pero cuando pregunto:

> ¿No tienes frío?

Las respuestas se vuelven más imprecisas:

- Sí.
- No.
- Sí, no tengo frío.
- Sí, sí tengo frío.
- No, no tengo frío.
- No, sí tengo frío.
- Afirmativo, sí tengo frío.
- Negativo, sí tengo frío.
- Afirmativo, no tengo frío.
- Negativo, no tengo frío.

Otro ejemplo

- FULANITO: ¿Me prestas tu lápiz?
- MENGANITO: No
- FULANITO: ¿No?
- MENGANITO: Sí, no te lo presto. / Afirmativo, no te lo presto.

Mi duda es cual es la manera correcta de contestar, dado que las respuestas para una pregunta que comienza con un "no" parecen ser muy relativas.

Comment: Creo que esas ambigüedades se producen más bien en otros casos: "¿Estás seguro de que no quieres más gaseosa?" "No" (¿no quieres o no estás seguro?) "Es verdad que no irás a la fiesta" "No" (¿no irás o no es verdad?) "¿Te dijo que no viene?" "No" (¿no te lo dijo, o no viene?).

Comment: Posible duplicado de: [Appropriate way to answer a negative yes/no question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/564/appropriate-way-to-answer-a-negative-yes-no-question)

Comment: Esto también sucede en otros idiomas, por ejemplo en japonés: [The reality of answering いいえ to a negative question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2908/the-reality-of-answering-%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%88-to-a-negative-question)

Comment: Y aquellas preguntas que dicen ej.: "¿No tienes frío?" Cómo se llaman?.. Recuerdo que una profesora en la básica nos dijo que aquellas preguntas tenían un nombre, el cual no recuerdo alguien sabe?...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 17):

No hay contradicción lógica. El *no* en las preguntas ejemplificadas imprime simplemente una opinión sesgada en la pregunta:

> ̣– ¿No tienes frío? (← ¿Tienes frío? + cierta espectativa de que la respuesta sea "sí, tengo frío")
>   –  No.

La respuesta significa lo mismo que "no, no tengo frío". En otros casos, generalmente, el *no* puede ser sustituido por advervios como *quizá*.

El último ejemplo necesita cierta interpretación para salvarlo de la "inconsistencia lógica". La respuesta *no* a la primera pregunga aquí

> FULANITO: ¿Me prestas tu lápiz?
>   MENGANITO: No
>   FULANITO: ¿No?
>   MENGANITO: Sí, no te lo presto. / Afirmativo, no te lo presto.

es simplemente *no, no te lo presto*. Después "FULANITO" pregunta "¿no?" sorprendido de la negación. "MENGANITO" responde hasta el final, *sí* y este *sí* significa *sí estás oyendo bien: no te lo presto*. En resumen:

> FULANITO: ¿Me prestas tu lápiz?
>   MENGANITO: No, no te lo presto
>   FULANITO: ¿Hablas en serio?
>   MENGANITO: Sí (=hablo en serio), no te lo presto.

Así mismo, en las respuestas, todas significan lo que está después de la coma: no hay suma lógica de ningún tipo.  Sin embargo, no todas son correctas:

> Sí.
>   No.
>   Sí, no tengo frío.  (Incorrecto)
>   Sí, sí tengo frío.
>   No, no tengo frío.
>   No, sí tengo frío.  (Incorrecto)
>   Afirmativo, sí tengo frío.  (Inusual)
>   Negativo, sí tengo frío.  (Incorrecto, inusual)
>   Afirmativo, no tengo frío.  (Incorrecto, inusual)
>   Negativo, no tengo frío.   (Inusual)

**EDIT:** Finalmente contestar con *afirmativo/negativo* da un estilo policial o de radiocomunicación (¿quizá porque una sola sílaba en una transmisión no muy clara, puede tener consecuencias graves?). Yo no lo usaría más que para bromear. Es demasiado raro (formal). Si ha de ser usada una palabra larga, **efectivamente** suena muy bien [1].

---

[1] Gracias a Arkana por la sugerencia.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. En el caso del lápiz me da la impresión de que el autor de la pregunta se refiere al `¿No?` como un `¿Seguro?`

Comment: @SysDragon Aquí también tienes razón. Modifico ahora mi respuesta.

Comment: Afirmativo y negativo se usan en transmisiones de radio, en los radios antiguos se tenía que decir eso en lugar de sí o no por que no se escuchaban bien, con los radios modernos ya no hay ese problema, pero por costumbre se quedo.

Comment: Espinoso tema el de las contradicciones y muy bien jugada la respuesta. Quizá podríamos añadir, como sinónimo menos formal de "afirmativo", la palabra "efectivamente": "Efectivamente, tengo frío".

Comment: En el español guatemalteco existe una palabra que soluciona perfectamente estas situaciones sin ambigüedad. _bien_ (analogo a _doch_ en alemán) significaría "sí tengo frío" (y _no_ significaría "no tengo frío")

Comment: En el inglés de hace algunos siglos tenían cuatro palabras (*yes*, *no*, *yea* y *nay*), que cubrían todos los casos posibles: respuesta afirmativa y negativa según fuera la pregunta afirmativa o negativa. Hoy día, en francés tienen tres palabras; la negativa siempre es *non*, pero la afirmativa puede ser *oui* (para pregunta afirmativa) o *si* (para pregunta negativa; parecido al *bien* que menciona @clinch para Guatemala). No conocía el *doch* alemán.

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que la manera mas práctica sería responder de manera directa independientemente de que la pregunta se formule de forma negativa o no. Por ejemplo:

> ¿No tienes frío?
>
> No, no tengo.
>
> Sí, si tengo.

Esto es en base a experiencia como hablante nativo.

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta el tipo y el contexto de la respuesta. "¿No tienes frío?" - "No"->"No, no tengo frío".

Comment: @c.p. Si lees la respuesta entera descubrirás que precisamente eso es lo que se concluye.

Answer (score 0):

En los primeros dos casos, al responder sólo SÍ o NO, son oraciones unimembres, donde el resto de los significados son tácitos (implícitos, no nombrados). Si yo pregunto "¿Llueve?" al responderme "Sí" significa "Sí llueve".

El problema es que ante ciertos casos, esas respuestas son ambiguas? Un caso obvio sería que yo pregunte, "¿Tu mascota es perro, o gato?" y me respondan "Sí". Puede ser tanto "Sí es perro", "Sí es gato" e incluso "Sí, es perro o gato, pero no sé cuál de los dos es?".

En este caso, responder "Sí" a "¿No tenés frío?" puede significar "Sí, no tengo frío" o "Sí tengo frío".

En este caso una persona más "digital" se inclinaría hacia la segunda acepción (que estás respondiendo a toda la pregunta), y una persona más "analógica" por la segunda.

Para saber qué es más común depende de la pregunta y no es algo que haya reglas fijas, sino más bien "sentido común" (aprender mediante la experiencia qué quiso decir el otro). Por eso, si bien tanto la pregunta, como cualquiera de las respuestas ("sí" o "no) son correctas, son malas preguntas y malas respuestas (sin llegar a ser incorrectas) porque son ambiguas.

En lugar de eso, hay formas de evitar esa ambigüedad. La primera es evitando la negación. La segunda (si se requiere preguntar en forma de negación), es "Es cierto que no tenés frío." o, mejor aún, "¿Es verdadero o es falso que no tenés frío?" (y esperar una respuesta del tipo verdadero/falso).